# Access value in object of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object, for-in-loop

I am using the cryptocompare npm package like this

```
const cc = require('cryptocompare');
cc.priceFull('ETH', 'USD')
  .then(prices => {
    console.log(prices);
  }).catch(console.error)
```

which returns me this:

```
{
    ETH: {
      USD: {
        TYPE: '5',
        MARKET: 'CCCAGG',
        FROMSYMBOL: 'ETH',
        TOSYMBOL: 'USD',
        FLAGS: '4',
        PRICE: 1152.42,
        LASTUPDATE: 1487865689,
        LASTVOLUME: 0.21,
        LASTVOLUMETO: 242.20349999999996,
        LASTTRADEID: 1224703,
        VOLUME24HOUR: 53435.45299122338,
        VOLUME24HOURTO: 60671593.843186244,
        OPEN24HOUR: 1119.31,
        HIGH24HOUR: 1170,
        LOW24HOUR: 1086.641,
        LASTMARKET: 'itBit',
        CHANGE24HOUR: 33.11000000000013,
        CHANGEPCT24HOUR: 2.958072383879366,
        SUPPLY: 16177825,
        MKTCAP: 18643649086.5
      }
   }
}
```

How can I now get the specific value (2.958072383879366) for **`CHANGEPCT24HOUR`**?

Tried a `for-in` loop to iterate through each object but still struggling with it.

Comment: `prices.ETH.USD["CHANGEPCT24HOUR"]`

Comment: 'ETH', 'USD' are dynamic for priceFull func ?

Comment: @shivshankar Yes, in the end it should be wrapped in another function to have it dynamic.

Comment: Please add the javascript tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below may help

```
// let a='ETH', b= 'USD'
const cc = require('cryptocompare');
cc.priceFull(a, b)
  .then(prices => {
    console.log(prices[a][b].CHANGEPCT24HOUR);
  }).catch(console.error)
```